# JQuery Validate bypassed after File Upload

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using JQuery Validate function to validate a form, which contains several input fields and two file uploads.

*The form is working fine. I can submit two files at the same time.*

And then comes the validation issue, here's the thing;

If I try to submit an empty form,  the error messages are shown for every required fields (no problem with that, that is what I intended to do in the first place). **But the validation rules are bypassed** (or the form getting submitted) **when the file uploads are filled, while the rest of the required fields are left empty**.

Here's my **JQuery** code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#MyForm").validate({

        errorElement: 'div',
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            photo: {
                required: true
            },
            cv: {
                required: true,
                extension: "pdf|doc|docx"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please fill in your name",
            photo: "Select your image file",
            cv: "Please upload your CV in PDF format",
            email: {
                required: "Please fill in your email address",
                email: "A valid email address should look like this: name@domain.com"
            },

        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });

});
```

And here's my **HTML** code:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" class="form-set" id="MyForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate" >
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Your Profile</legend>
        <label class="control-label" for="cname">Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="cname" name="name"/>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="cemail">Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="cemail" name="email"/>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="cphoto">Photo</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="file" id="cphoto" name="photo">
        </div>
        <label class="control-label" for="ccv">CV</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="file" name="cv" id="ccv">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Can somebody point me out, where to look?

Comment: Where is the HTML markup of the form?

Comment: @Ryley did provide us with a working example. The HTML form is similar with the one he provided.

Comment: It doesn't matter what's in the answers.  It's up to you to provide enough code for a concise example and make your question fully self contained.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I jot it there to make it clear to everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

The most likely issue is that you haven't included the file `additional-methods.js` from the jQuery Validate package.  That's where the `extension` method exists.

Second, and this is just preference, but if all you are doing in your `submitHandler` is submitting the form, you don't need to have it at all - just get rid of that option and it will automatically submit.

I created a working example of your code, and it correctly demands your name even if you fill in the two file dialogs correctly.  http://jsfiddle.net/ryleyb/C5k7z/

Comment: Thank you, @Ryley :D
Your answer point me to the right direction, yes, it was all about **file dependencies**. Beside the required 'additional-methods.js' there was another validation script that was included (through another plugin I use in my site).

Thank you very much, I appreciate it.